# CSS Styling alignment

Tags: html, css

good evening. The below code is for my navigation bar on my website.The two unordered lists are currently sat side by side (inline) which is what I wanted. However, I would like the second  sat over on the right had side. I know there are several ways to achieve this. My question is specific to this method, as I do not understand why it is happening. Why is it, if I add the following code to my style sheet (.float { float: right }), the second  moves to the right, but does *not* stay 'inline' with the first ; it shows on a slightly different level? I do not understand why this is the case. Would someone be kind enough to explain?

Secondly, if I add a different class to each of the unordered lists and float one to the right and one to left, simaultaneously removing the CSS (  .nav ul {display: inline; ), I do not understand why it is that they sit 'inline' with each other? What is instructing them to do so? How does a float: right instruction, also instruct the element to move up besides the one on the left? Many Thanks
      display: inline;
     }

http://jsfiddle.net/mugman/rnmht1y2/

```
 <body>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="float">
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>

    <style>

    .nav a {
      color: #5a5a5a;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 14px 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }

   .nav li {
       display: inline;
      }

   .nav ul {
      display: inline;
     }
```

Comment: As you'll see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) float changes the display type to `block`, which is displayed different than inline.

Comment: A lot of the code seems to be missing. On a side note, <style> should be in <head>.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost Styles should not be in the head. Actually, in HTML you can add 'scoped' style blocks to specific elements, so they only apply to specific parts of the document.

Comment: Are you just asking about the `float` and why it does what it does or would you like a solution as well?

Comment: @GolezTrol As a side note, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) reports that the only browser that currently supports scoped CSS is Firefox. Development of this feature is not on the workplan for IE at all and Chrome had it as an experimental feature but has since removed it. It seems to have very little support now and doesn't look promising for future releases.

Comment: I see Sharf, so the very fact that I am using the float attribute removes the element from the normal flow of the page, causes it to adopt the attributes of a block element, thus preventing it from sitting on the same line as the first unordered list. Thank you.

Comment: Hi War10ck, I was primary asking about the float, however any solution you can give would always be welcome, for my education if nothing else.

Comment: @Sharf - Although, does my second question not contradict this solution? As in the case, both unordered lists have 'float' attributes, but sit comfortably side by side? Would this not contradict that block elements cannot sit side by side on a page? I'm confused.

Comment: @mugman blocks can sit side by side perfectly comfortably, as long as they are floating. The problem is, your are using `inline-block` which is presumably aligned to the `baseline` and the floating `block` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element is said to be inline-level when the calculated value of its display CSS property is: inline, inline-block or inline-table. Visually, it doesn't constitute blocks of contents but is distributed in lines with other inline-level content. Typically content of a paragraph, being text, with different formatting like emphasis, or images, is made from inline-level elements.
(from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model)

If you apply inline-block to your "nav ul" your elements will display inline.

```css
.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.float {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="float">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```